# how to show that the compactness of set implies closedness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n $. Then the following statements are equivalent
>   a) $S$ is compact
>   b) $S$ is closed and bounded
>   c) Every infinite subset $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$

I think I terribly misunderstood the **compactness** and **open covering**. It's clear that $b) \implies a)$, I am having hard time to understand why $a) \implies b)$, isn't the open interval $(1,3)$ covered by finite open sub-covering of the form $(n,n +1)$.

The proof of my book can be summarized as follows.

Let $y$ be accumulation point in $S| y \notin S , \forall x \in S,$ choose $r_x = \frac12||x-y||$, then $ \{ B(x, r_x): x \in S\}  $ is open sub-covering of $S$.i.e $S \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^p B(x_k, r_x )$, choosing $r = \frac 12 \min\{r_k\}$, we can show that $\cup_{k=1}^nB(x_k, r) \cap B(y, r) = \emptyset$.

But what's the point? don't we have freedom to choose our $r$? If we define the covering this way, no matter how many open sub-covers we make, we will never cover this the region between $r$ and $y$??

Comment: $(1,3)$ is indeed covered by a finite subcover of $(n,n+1)$. But this doesn't make it compact, as you need every open cover to have a finite subcover

Comment: @Nameless suppose, we have a closed set instead $[1, 3]$, still there would be infinite subcovers. But we would be able to extract a fine subcovers that also covers it? Is that the point? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: $[1,3]$ is compact. Thus, for every (infinite) open cover there is a finite subcover. If you find an infinite cover, then you can find a finite subcover as well

Comment: @Nameless I'm sorry again :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

> The proof of my book can be summarized as follows.
>
> Let $y$ be accumulation point in $S\mid y \notin S , \forall x \in S,$ choose $r_x = \frac12\|x-y\|$, then $ \{ B(x, r_x): x \in S\}  $ is open sub-covering of $S$.i.e $S \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^p B(x_k, r_x )$, choosing $r = \frac 12 \min\{r_k\}$, we can show that $\cup_{k=1}^nB(x_k, r) \cap B(y, r) = \emptyset$.

Part of the problem is that the proof in the book **cannot** be summarized that way (unless the book is so badly written that you’d be better off throwing it away!).

- $\{B(x,r_x):x\in S\}$ is not an ‘open sub-covering of $S$’; it’s the open cover of $S$ with which you’re starting.
- You never say what $x_1,\dots,x_p$ are.
- The notation $B(x_k,r_k)$ is undefined: either you must write $B(x_k,r_{x_k})$, or for $k=1,\dots,p$ you must define $r_k=r_{x_k}$ and **then** write $B(x_k,r_k)$.
- There is no need for the factor of $\frac12$ in the definition of $r$ (though I suppose that the author might have added this unnecessary touch).

Here’s a correct version, with a little extra explanatory detail:

> Let $y$ be an accumulation point of $S$ that is not in $S$. For each $x\in S$ let $r_x=\frac12\|x-y\|$; since $y\notin S$, $\|x-y\|>0$ for all $x\in S$, and therefore $r_x>0$ for each $x\in S$. Thus, $\{B(x,r_x):x\in S\}$ is an open cover of $S$. Since $S$ is compact, this cover has a finite subcover; that is, there is a finite set $\{x_1,\dots,x_p\}\subseteq S$ such that $\{B(x_k,r_{x_k}):k=1,\dots,p\}$ covers $S$, i.e., $S\subseteq\bigcup_{k=0}^pB(x_k,r_{x_k})$. Now $\{r_1,\dots,r_p\}$ is a finite set of positive real numbers, so $\min\{r_1,\dots,r_p\}>0$. Let $r=\min\{r_1,\dots,r_p\}$; then $B(y,r)\cap S\subseteq B(y,r)\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^pB(x_k,r_{x_k})=\varnothing$, because $B(y,r)\cap B(x_k,r_{x_k})=\varnothing$ for $k=1,\dots,p$. To see this, suppose that $z\in B(y,r)\cap B(x_k,r_{x_k})$; then $$\|x_k-y\|\le\|y-z\|+\|z-x_k\|<r+r_{x_k}\le 2r_{x_k}=\|x_k-y\|\;,$$ which is absurd. (The step $r+r_{x_k}\le 2r_{x_k}$ is justified by the fact that $r\le r_k$.)
>
> But then $B(y,r)$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ disjoint from $S$, contradicting the hypothesis that $y$ is an accumulation point of $S$. This contradiction shows that every accumulation point of $S$ must in fact belong to $S$ and hence that $S$ is closed. $\dashv$

Note that this is essentially the same argument that copper.hat gives in his answer; it’s just arranged to stay a bit closer to the one that you summarized incorrectly.

The intuitive idea is really fairly simple. Since $y\notin S$, we can cover $S$ with open balls so small that $y$ isn’t even in the closure of any of them; that’s what we’re doing when we choose the radii $r_x$ to be **less** than the distance from $x$ to $y$. (We actually took $r_x$ to be half the distance from $x$ to $y$, but that was just a convenience; anything less than $\|x-y\|$ would work.) Then we use the compactness of $S$ to say that we don’t actually need all of these open balls $B(x,r_x)$: finitely many of them are already enough to cover $S$. Let these finitely many open balls be $B(x_k,r_{x_k})$ for $k=1,\dots,p$. For $k=1,\dots,p$ let $\overline{B}(x_k,r_{x_k})=\{z\in\Bbb R^n:\|z-x_k\|\le r_{x_k}\}$, the closed ball of radius $r_{x_k}$ centred at $x_k$. We chose each $r_x$ to be less than the distance from $x$ to $y$, so $y$ is not in any of these closed balls, and therefore it’s not in their union:

$$y\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^p\overline{B}(x_k,r_{x_k})\;.\tag{1}$$

The righthand side of $(1)$ is the union of finitely many closed sets, so it is itself a closed set, and it contains $S$. Every closed set that contains $S$ also contains the closure of $S$, so $y$ is not in the closure of $S$, contradicting the hypothesis that $y$ is an accumulation point of $S$. (Or, if you arrange the argument as copper.hat did, showing directly that the complement of $S$ is open and hence that $S$ is closed.)

---

Finally, as copper.hat says, ‘$S$ is compact’ does **not** mean that $S$ has a finite open cover. It means that **no matter what** open cover of $S$ you start with, that open cover has a finite subcover. If you can find just one open cover of $S$ that has no finite subcover, then $S$ is not compact. Finding one open cover of $S$ that **does** have a finite subcover, on the other hand, tells you absolutely nothing about whether $S$ is compact.

Comment: is it possible to have an example of an example of finite sub-cover of open covering closed set? Like $\{(1/n, 2/n): n \ge 2\}$ forms open infinite covering, similarly can we have for $[0,1]$ but finite one?

Comment: @experimentX: I’m not sure what you’re asking: $[0,1]$ is compact, so **every** open cover of $[0,1]$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: I mean example of open cover of [0,1] having finite subcovers

Comment: @experimentX: Pick any open cover of $[0,1]$ that you like: it has a finite subcover. For instance, the open cover $$\left\{\left(-1,\frac1{100}\right)\right\}\cup\left\{\left(\frac1n,2\right):n \ge 2 \right\}$$ has $$\left\{\left(-1,\frac1{100}\right),\left(\frac1{101},2\right)\right\}$$ as a finite subcover.

Comment: but this also covers (0,1). What is the difference? Sorry for asking unnecessary questions.

Comment: @experimentX: **Every** cover of $[0,1]$ must necessarily cover $(0,1)$ as well, since $(0,1)\subseteq[0,1]$. It must also cover $\left(\frac14,\frac34\right)$, $\left[\frac12,1\right)$, and every other subset of $[0,1]$. This is irrelevant to the compactness of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

$S$ is covered by $\bigcup_{x\in S}B(x,r_x)$ and as $S$ is compact, $S\subseteq  \bigcup_{k=1}^p B(x_k,r_{x_k})$. If we choose $r=\min\left\{r_{x_k}\right\}>0$ then it is true that $B(x_k,r)\cap B(y,r)=\emptyset$ and so $$S\cap  B(y,r)\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^p B(x_k,r_{x_k})\cap  B(y,r)=\emptyset$$ which is a contradiction as $y$ is a limit point of $S$.

I sincerely do not understand your questions. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: sorry .. fixed again.

Comment: @experimentX Now that there are no more typos, lets concentrate on the problem. What is it you don't understand in this proof?

Comment: Could you explain your first comment? If i understand that, i might understand the most of it.

Comment: $(1,3)  \subset \cup_0^3 (n, n+1)$ but why is it not compact?

Comment: Compact means **every** open subcover has a finite subcover. You have picked just one open cover. Another would be $\{\mathbb{R}^n\}$, which 'works' for all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @experimentX This is true. What you did is construct an open cover with a finite subcover. But as copper hat says, you want **all** covers to have a finite subcover.

Comment: I see the ... where i wen't wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier and more instructive to show a) $\Rightarrow$ b) directly.

The key is that **every** open cover has a finite subcover. $(1,3)$ has the open cover $\{(1+\frac{1}{n},3)\}_n$, but it has no finite subcover, hence is not compact.

If $S$ is compact, then every open cover has a finite subcover. So take $\{B(0,n)\}_n$. This is an open cover of $S$, hence has a finite subcover, hence $S \subset B(0,n')$ for some $n'$. Hence $S$ is bounded.

Now suppose $y \notin S$. For each $x \in C$, there exists some $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $|y-x| \geq \epsilon_x$, or in other words, $y \notin B(x,\epsilon_x)$. Now consider the open cover $\{B(x,\frac{1}{2} \epsilon_x)\}_{x \in S}$. Since $S$ is compact, there is a finite subcover $\{B(x_i, \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{x_i})\}_i$, and so $C \subset \cup_i B(x_i, \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{x_i})$. By construction, if $x \in B(x_i, \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{x_i})$, then $|y-x| \geq \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{x_i}$, hence if we take $\delta = \frac{1}{2}\min_i \epsilon_{x_i}$, we have $B(y,\delta) \cap S = \emptyset$, and hence we have that $S^C$ is open. Hence $S$ is closed.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the corrections. I was thinking under the influence.